# Is it possible to use the "with" keyword, in Python, on MySQL-Connector cursors and connections?

Tags: python, mysql-connector, with-statement

Similar to how when opening files it is recommended to use `with open('myfile', 'r') as f:` instead of `f=open('myfile', 'r')'` and `f.close()`, my question is that if it is possible to do the same with the `mysql.connector.connect()` and `<connection>.cursor()` functions in the Python MySQL module.

If so, how should i do it?
So far I've been using decorators to achieve the same result.

Comment: Supposedly, yes: https://realpython.com/python-mysql/

Comment: A connection is typically held for the life of the application, so I'm not sure that's really a gain, and a cursor can be reused.  So, even if possible, it might not be appropriate.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @TimRoberts
The reason I'm trying this is because whenever i try to do any operation in my database concurrently (Say, I'm trying to update a row in phpmyadmin or MySQLWorkbench), it will show as "loading", but won't end unless I close my python program.
Therefore I assumed the reason to be that it can't do anything while i have either a cursor or a connection, so I've decided to rewrite my functions so they either open and close their cursors (In case that is what causes the problem) or their connections (For the same reason).

Comment: Unless you have your database configured incorrectly, a connection in program 1 should have absolutely zero impact on a connection in program 2.  That's the whole freakin' point of having a database server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example

```
from mysql.connector import connect

with connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="username",
    password="password",
) as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE myDB")
```